# Use property during interface initialization?

Tags: typescript

Is something like this possible in TypeScript? If so, what is the proper syntax?

```
return {
    serviceA: new ServiceA(db),
    serviceB: new ServiceB(serviceA), // this.serviceA?
}
```

I know I could pull `serviceA` out, but I think it's not really elegant. Using TypeScript 2.3.

In case it's not possible, is there an actual rationale behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because (probably) it's not possible in JavaScript and TypeScript is just a superset that adds types.

Also, since it's trivial (and reasonably readable) to do something like

```
const serviceA = new ServiceA(dB);
return { serviceA, serviceB: new ServiceB(serviceA) };
```

There's probably no reason to actually implement it.

One of the guiding principles of TypeScript is to stray as little as possible from the ECMAScript standard.